# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, render

im working on react and i got this error it doesnt seem like there is an error to me but the code didnt work tho. i hope anyone can help with a fix. here is the code updated below: the code is for a cartPage but the cart page is running. this error just pop up when i click the cart icon with items only.

```
  import React from 'react'

function UserCardBlock(props) {

    const renderCartImage = (images) => {
        if(images.length > 0) {
            let image = images[0]
            return `http://localhost:5000/${image}`
        }
    }

    const renderItems = () => (
        props.products && props.products.map(product => (
            <tr key={product._id}>
                <td>
                    <img style={{ width: '70px' }} alt="product" 
                    src={renderCartImage(product.images)} />
                </td> 
                <td>{product.quantity} EA</td>
                <td>$ {product.price} </td>
                <td><button 
                onClick={()=> props.removeItem(product._id)}
                >Remove </button> </td>
            </tr>
        ))
    )

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Image</th>
                        <th>Product Quantity</th>
                        <th>Product Price</th>
                        <th>Remove from Cart</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {renderItems()}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default UserCardBlock
```

Comment: Apparently props.products is not an array. Can you show us where you're passing in the prop?

Answer (score 1):

`props.products` is not an Array.
I think you should try `Array.isArray(props.products) && ...`

Answer (score 0):

props.products existis but it's not an Array. Try `console.log(props.products);` to see the value or post the rest of code.